# Nested Transactions in ADO.NET

Tags: c#, .net

First, is it possible to have n transactions levels over ADO.Net.  Second, is this correct usage?

```
        var tx = cx.BeginTransaction();

        cx.Execute("insert into atable(id) values(123123)");

        var tx2=tx.BeginTransaction();

        cx.Execute("insert into atable(id) values(123127)");

        tx2.Commit();

        tx.Commit();
```

... 
etc.

Comment: can you clarify why do you want to do this?

Comment: Why are you using different transactions in the fist place? You are only executing one action at a time and that is already transactional, either the insert commits or it doesn't. What is it that you're trying to accomplish? It seems as if you only need one transaction for the whole process.

Comment: @PedroC88: this is just an example.  It's easier to illustrate with something easy.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can nest transactions using [`TransactionScope`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transactionscope.transactionscope.aspx) - however, they will only get committed once the most outer one gets committed.

They will all be rolled back if any one of them will rollback.

In terms of usage - you should wrap the transaction creation in `using` statements to ensure proper disposal.

```
using(var tx1 = new TransactionScope())
{
   cx.Execute("insert into atable(id) values(123123)");

   using(var tx2 = new TransactionScope())
   {
        cx.Execute("insert into atable(id) values(123127)");
        tx2.Complete();
   }

   tx1.Complete()
}
```

Comment: looks like a vendor issue then.  Thanks.

Comment: are you missing constructor arguments to TransactionScope?

Comment: @sgtz - It has an empty parameterless constructor. You can specify several different parameters if you wish, though.

Comment: that works.  ty.  How does c# associate the TransactionScope object to the connection / transaction?  Is there some compiler magic going on here?  I still wish I knew why the second commit in my example was failing for me.  Oh well.

Comment: @sgtz - It uses the [ambient transaction](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transaction.current.aspx). Take a look at the links in the article.

Comment: ty for the elegant solution.  I was going to look at doing this with AOP in month or so, but no need now that I've seen this.  Still not sure how they implement an ambient transaction, but I'll dig into it later.  Thanks for the link.

Comment: Why would they all roll back if  you're only rolling back a single inner transaction, undoing it's work only, then committing the outer transaction?

Comment: @Triynko - the exception caused by the inner transaction would bubble up - the outer transaction would not complete. There are no try/catch blocks.

Comment: I believe the usage of TransactionScope shown above is incorrect.  TransactionScope must be declared **before** SqlConnection is opened for it to work properly.  I have confirmed this by checking the value of @@TRANCOUNT.  You would see the value is 0 if TransactionScope is defined after SqlConnection is opened, and the value is 1 if TransactionScope is defined before.  It is also mentioned in this [article](https://blog.appliedis.com/2015/05/27/the-magic-of-transactionscope/), search for "This is your only warning"