# SqlConnection and nested transactions

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net, sql-server-2012, .net-4.5

There's (still) no way to create nested transactions via ADO.NET / SQL Server 2012, correct? This ...

```
using (var sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(connStr))
{
    sqlConnection.Open();
    var tranOuter = sqlConnection.BeginTransaction("outer");
    DoStuff();

        var tranInner = sqlConnection.BeginTransaction("inner");
        DoMoreStuff();
        tranInner.Commit();


    tranOuter.Commit();
}
```

... throws **SqlConnection does not support parallel transactions**. So I'll probably have to re-write my code to use [TransactionScope](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transactionscope.aspx) everywhere, or am I missing something?

EDIT: naming transactions doesn't help

EDIT: looks like this is a [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9909348/nested-transactions-in-ado-net)

Comment: It would probably help if you were to use one of the `overloads` to name your `Transactions` I have done this before and have had zero issues with doing nested transactions also do not assume that the `Commit` will be successful try wrapping both the 
`tranInner & tramOuter` into their own separate `try{}catch{}` statements and do a `Rollback` if the commit fails

Comment: Nope, naming doesn't fix the problem. The exception is thrown by sqlConnection.BeginTransaction("inner");

Comment: I see nowhere in your code where you are creating the `SQLTransaction` object..

Comment: @DJKRAZE sqlConnection.BeginTransaction creates it.

Comment: Why not try it a different way but explicitly creating the SqlTransaction object and assigning the transaction properly that way.. like I've stated I know that approach works

Comment: possible duplicate of [Nested Transactions in ADO.NET](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9909348/nested-transactions-in-ado-net)