# .NET 4.0 transaction behavior when calling stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures, transactions

If I create a `SqlConnection` and do not create a `SqlTransaction` for it from C# code and then use a `SqlCommand` to invoke a stored procedure, what is the transactional behavior of the code in the following two scenarios

1. Stored procedure does not have any `BEGIN TRANSACTION` statements
2. Stored procedure has a single `BEGIN TRANSACTION` at start and ends with a `COMMIT TRANSACTION`.

Assume that no errors occur that would cause the transactions to rollback

From what I understand, the stored procedure would be invoked outside a transaction and cause the following behavior:

1. Each statement in the stored procedure would execute in its own transaction
2. The transaction opened in the stored procedure would be the top level transaction and all statements in the stored procedure would be associated with that transaction.

Please comment if my understanding in scenarios in A and B is correct.

Comment: Transactions don't nest the way one would expect. If I remember correctly, each begin trans increments a counter, commit decrements it and it commits for real when it gets to 0. Now when you mix TSQL and ADO.NET transactions you can get unexpected results. In general, use one or the other, but not both. Ref: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9909348/nested-transactions-in-ado-net  and the other thing that happens are zombie transactions

Comment: @GameSalutes, I think what you stated is correct, I did a test with a SP which raiserror before insertion some records to an existing table, I can see the records is successfully inserted and an Exception also caught in the .net code side.

Answer (score 0):

Your understanding of the scenarios of A and B is correct.

People prefer ADO.NET transaction when lot of UI side data interaction is involved and people prefer to tackle it at UI Side. Otherwise you have to pass on all the data to the SQL Side and let it handle it which sometimes becomes a overhead.